# Xampp showing error code 1058 and gets terminated while trying to run

Tags: xampp

when i open xampp control panelv 3.1.0 it show the following error..when i try to run it shows some other error and xampp gets terminated.I saw there is some issue with skype first i changed the port and than i removed the skpe to chek the issue. i am using windows xp. someone please help me. thanks in advance.

`9:28:00 PM  [main]     Initializing Control Panel
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows XP SP2 32-bit
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  enter code here XAMPP Version: 1.8.1
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.1.0 3.1.0 [ Compiled: September 20th 2012 ]
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  Running with Administrator rights - good!
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
    9:28:00 PM  [mysql]     MySQL Service detected with wrong path
    9:28:00 PM  [mysql]     Change XAMPP MySQL settings or
    9:28:00 PM  [mysql]     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
    9:28:00 PM  [mysql]     Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server             5.0\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini" MySQL
    9:28:00 PM  [mysql]     Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
    9:28:00 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready`

Answer (score 0):

fixed mysql by using the following command in command prompt
`sc delete mysql`

but apache stil unable to start...when click on start show error 1062 and gets terminated...